# IntelliJ Maven "Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile"

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) to develop `Java` Desktop applications. On my project, I added framework support for [`Maven`](https://maven.apache.org/) and added a dependency to the `pom.xml` file. I also added a build artifact like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639682/defining-multiple-artifacts-with-same-project-but-different-main-classes) (I would also appreciate if this question gets answered).
Now that my project has `Maven` support, the generated `JAR` file no longer works. When I try to launch it, it displays the error `Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile MyProject.jar`. When I open the `JAR` file using [`WinRAR`](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm), there is no `MANIFEST.MF` file included, only folders and `CLASS` files. What happened to my `Maven` dependencies as well? Why does `IntelliJ` not properly build my `Maven` project into an executable `JAR` file via its artifacts?

Answer (score 42):

1. Go to **Module Settings** --> **Artifacts**
2. Create a new folder called **META-INF**
   [image]
3. Add the **MANIFEST** file which should be located in your src folder
   [image]

**as a file**

[image]

This will tell IntelliJ to copy the manifest into the jar file.

Comment: note: Module Settings is in File -> Project Structure