# Generate .JAR from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar

I am attempting to create a JAR from IntelliJ using the build artifacts but when I do it is saying

```
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile
```

Im not sure what im doing wrong though?[image]

[image]

Comment: just curious -- why do you need IntelliJ to create the JAR? A Maven or Gradle build script could do the job, and would be portable to Continuous Integration environments, easy to share with teammates, yada yada.

Comment: Is it the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32654152/intellij-maven-error-invalid-or-corrupt-jarfile ?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from what you have posted. Intellij can be finicky at times especially with the Artifact jar build interface. There is a good tutorial on IntelliJ's website on how to set up the artifact. One area that may provide difficulty is pointing to the Main Class.

An issue I had in building a jar using the tool was selecting the Main Class. Ultimately I typed it in and it worked. Not sure if this is the advice that will solve your problem.

From the intellij website at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html

Note the image below.

Other potential issues could be that a dependency was corrupted, although doubtful.

Could also be the Manifest file is referencing a file that is causing the issue. Most Manifest files should be fairly simple and point to the main class. Last but not least email IntelliJ. They are good at responding and if the problem is one that intellij can solve, they will help.  Unfortunately they only respond by email and sometimes can take up to a day.

[image: ---]

Comment: I tried that, followed the guide to a T. I still get the same error.

Comment: For my web application I use the Maven Clean and Build tools to build the Jar. Gradle has similar tools but am not familiar with them.